# How to convert a string to an attribute when the string has the same value with the attribute

Tags: python, class

```py
class Person:  
  __name = ""
  __contacts = [] 
  __age = 0
  __vaccination_state = False
  __health_state = True 
  __quarantine_state = True 
  __symptom = "symptomatic" 

  def __init__(self, name, contacts, age, vaccination_state, health_state, quarantine_state, symptom):
    self.__name = name
    self.__age = age 
    self.__contacts = contacts 
    self.__vaccination_state = vaccination_state
    self.__health_state = health_state
    self.__quarantine_state = quarantine_state
    self.__symptom = symptom 

  def GetName(self):
    return self.__name

  def GetAge(self):
    return self.__age
  
  def GetContacts(self):
    return self.__contacts

  def GetVaccination(self):
    return self.__vaccination_state

  def GetHealth(self):
    return self.__health_state

  def GetQuarantine(self):
    return self.__quarantine_state

  def GetSymptom(self):
    return self.__symptom
 
  def SetName(self, name):
    self.__name = name

  def SetAge(self, age):
    self.__age = age

  def SetAllContacts(self, contacts):
    self.__contacts = contacts 

  def AddSingleContact(self, contact):
    self.__contacts.append(contact)

  def SetVaccination(self, vaccination_state):
    self.__vaccination_state = vaccination_state

  def SetHealth(self, healthState):
    self.__health_state = healthState
    self.CheckPositive()

  def SetQuarantine(self, quarantine_state):
    self.__quarantine_state = quarantine_state
  
  def SetSymptom(self, symptom):
    self.__symptom = symptom 
  def CheckPositive(self):
    if self.__health_state == False: 
      self.__quarantine_state = True
      start = datetime.datetime.now()
      end = start + datetime.timedelta(10)
      for i in range(len(self.__contacts)):
        getattr(Person, self.GetContacts()[i]).SetQuarantine(True)
        print(self.GetContacts()[i], " and his/her close contacts have been notified.\n", "Quarantine starts at", start, "and ends at", end)
        for i in range(len(self.__contacts)):
          getattr(Person, self.GetContacts()[i]).SetQuarantine(True)

A = Person("A", ["Z"], 17, True, True, False, "NA")
Z = Person("Z", ["A"], 17, True, True, False, "NA")
A.SetHealth(False)
```

SetQuarantine(True)is a function in the class that I want to call. the returned value of self.GetContacts(i) is a list. so the self.GetContacts()[i] is a string, for example, "name". But I want to get an attribute so that I can call the function SetQuarantine(True). This attribute has the same value with the string but I don't know how to convert it.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you give us the code for the `Person` class? As it currently stands, you haven't given us a minimally reproducible example, which makes it harder for us to diagnose the issue.

Comment: what does `self.__contacts` contain? is it the same list that would be returned by `self.GetContacts`? also provide a [mre]

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I just edited the codes and I set health statue of A to false and by logic, Z's quarantine status should be set into True. But as it's a string it couldn't call a function. Could you help me to call the function that could trigger the function SetQuarantine()? Thank you @BrokenBenchmark

Comment: @Matiiss Thank you for your comment. I answered your question in reply for BrokenBenchmark.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem stems from attempting to perform this: `getattr(Person, self.GetContacts()[i]).SetQuarantine(True)`. You're trying to access a `Person.Z` attribute, which doesn't exist. Python throws an error as a result.

There's two things you need to do to fix this:

1. **Don't (attempt to) use class-level variables.** Class-level variables should be used when you want data to be shared across all instances of a class. Since different instances of Person can have different contacts, using class-level variables makes little sense here.
2. **In each instance of Person, you need to store a reference to a Person object for each contact**, as opposed to their name. This lets you set a close contact's quarantine status directly. (Even if you were to create a lookup table of names, that table wouldn't be able to handle two people with the same name.)

Here's a modified `CheckPositive` function as well as some modifed driver code:

```py
def CheckPositive(self):
  if self.__health_state == False: 
    self.__quarantine_state = True
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    end = start + datetime.timedelta(10)
    for i in range(len(self.__contacts)):
      print(self.__contacts[i].GetName(), "has been notified.\n", "Quarantine starts at", start, "and ends at", end)
      self.__contacts[i].SetQuarantine(True)

A = Person("A", [], 17, True, True, False, "NA")
Z = Person("Z", [], 17, True, True, False, "NA")
A.AddSingleContact(Z)
Z.AddSingleContact(A)
A.SetHealth(False)
```